# EmberJS 2.0 How to avoid Dynamic Segments On route to be always undefined?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to access to the dynamic segment on a route but the params are always undefined.

I have the next route defined on the router:

```
this.route('send', {path: '/send/:solName/:id/:userId'}, function() {});
```

And In my route I have this:

```
    export default Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function (params){

        console.info(params);

        return {
             solName: params.solName,
             id: params.id,
             userId: params.userId
         }

        }
      });
```

Any idea why the params are always undefined?

Comment: Which path or link do you hit?

Comment: for example I try to use on the browser #/send/IT/033712-31-01-2017-192142982/55 and I try to use this.transitionToRoute('send.index', params) from a controller and every time the params on the route are empty

Comment: what is the path for route file you put in the question?

Comment: I used ember-cli to create the route and this is the path it generates /routes/send/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal.

The dynamic segment parameters would not passed to inner routes.

You need to use `paramsFor` method in `send.index` route to get params sent to the route.

Please check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3867a3d265b5fd85b37cfc3f5d67cc81) out

Comment: Ok that works, just one more question if I have to retrive the params for a subroute of send, how should I make the call on paramsFor?

Comment: @DeividKamui I showed that in the twiddle, in the subroute send.index